# How to read 'unrecognized selector' error logs in obj-c / iphone apps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, crash

i've got the following crash log error in my app:

```
-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x194adc8
```

How do i read this? Does it mean that:

- I sent a 'length' message to a '`NSNull`' object?
- The 'length' method in the '`NSNull`' class crashed when trying to call a selector on another class?

Also, if it is the former option, how can i get the stack trace to see which function caused this crash? That top line is the only error in my log.

Thanks

Comment: I just want to point that sending unrecognized selector to object do not crash app. That must be a sign that your app is doing something wrong around there, though.

Comment: This is simply wrong. Sending an `unrecognized selector` does crash an application - hence the `NSInvalidArgumentException` that gets thrown. Maybe you are referring to compilation? You can compile an app that sends an incorrect selector and only receive a `warning`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Door 1

`NSNull` does not respond to `length`

You can check the documentation for [NSNull](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to see that this is the case.

Without having an idea of what your code base is doing I am not sure where to look, you must be calling `[NSNull null];` at some point to get the `NSNull` object or you are using a framework somewhere that returns this.

Comment: Analyze the line which causes the error, and check which object trying to do the method call, in my case my error was to use method instead of property.

Answer (score 2):

It means you sent 'length' to NSNull and NSNull doesn't have a 'length' function.

Turning on NSZombies might help you (it keeps deallocated objects around so it can tell you which object you tried to access) but I think in this case you probably set an object to NSNull at some point (or it was returned from a function).

Anyway to turn on NSZombies, go to Project > Edit Active Executable > Arguments tab > Then add a variable called NSZombieEnabled and set the value to YES.  Make sure you turn it off when you're done though because it can cause memory issues.

Comment: I'm using xcode 4.2 and can't find a project or edit active executable menu anywhere. Thanks for the tip though. However, i don't think it's a zombie issue, because the NSNull is happily alive.

Comment: How would `NSZombies` help in this situation? This is not a case of accessing memory that has been released. This is accessing a valid object of type `NSNull`.

Comment: It's a useful thing to know about, regardless.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you are using a Length method for calculating the string length

Like
    If([strText Length]>0)
    {
    //do something here----
    }
    else
    {
    //Do somethig here--
    }

So in above case- strText is NSNull then definitely a crash will accure and GDB will show a message like:
[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

As above told already Null don't have Length method.

For rescue:
 check first:
        if ((NSNull *)strText == [NSNull null])
        {
            return strText=@"";
        }
This will prevent for crash for NSNULL

Comment: How to return strText = @"";  IF I put this error will be generated.

Comment: This check need to put inside a method that is calling: Suppose You created a method:                 (NSString*)replaceXmlEncodingFromString:(NSString*)stringToReplace
{
 NSString *sURL;  
    if ((NSNull *)stringToReplace == [NSNull null])
    {
        return sURL=@"";
    }   if([stringToReplace length]!=0)
 { //--do something                                                  }
  
}

Comment: This is my method where i got error.                                          if ( [txtUsername.text length]> 0 ) {
        
  [slUsersController searchByLogin:txtUsername.text];

 }                                                           sometime it works but sometime not.

Comment: Fine: Just replace ur method code by I giving you.  ---- if ((NSNull *)txtUsername.text == [NSNull null])
 {
 //do nothing bcoz username is null
} 

else
{
if ( [txtUsername.text length]> 0 ) 
{ 
[slUsersController searchByLogin:txtUsername.text]; 

}
}

Comment: I have implemented your code but,it still not working. Is it necessary to call return [NSNull nsnull]; at the end of this method?

Comment: no need to return [NSNull nsnull]; at the end of method until method return type is non void. Can you put a slog inside if and else so that u can know where it reach and crashed or may use breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

Zombies won't help in this case.  As Paul.s said, NSNull is a valid object.  You should get the stack trace when the app stops.  Do you have the debugger pane open?  Make sure it is.  I'm pretty sure Xcode 4 always stops on exceptions with the stack trace.  If for some reason you're still not seeing it, if you are at the (gdb) prompt, you can type 'bt' (backtrace) to get the trace.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are coparing NSNull class to lenth

check before fo that

```
    if ([NSString *str isKindOfClass:[NSNull null]]){
       str=@"";
    }
```

then check length for the str.

it works!thx